# Foreach loop in bash

Tags: bash, foreach, grep

I have two files, one with about 100 root domains, and second file with URLs only. Now I have to filter that URL list to get third file which contains only URLs that have domains from the list.

Example of URL list:

```
| URL                           |
| ------------------------------|
| http://github.com/name        |
| http://stackoverflow.com/name2|
| http://stackoverflow.com/name3|
| http://www.linkedin.com/name3 |
```

Example of word list:

```
github.com
youtube.com
facebook.com
```

Resut:

```
| http://github.com/name        |
```

My goal is to filter out whole row where URL contain specific word. This is what I tried:

```
for i in $(cat domains.csv); 
 do grep "$i" urls.csv >> filtered.csv ; 
done
```

Result is strange, I've got some of the links, but not all of them that contain root domains from the first file. Then I tried to do the same thing with python and saw that bash doesn't do what I wanted, I've got better result with python script, but it takes more time to write python script than running bash commands.

How shoud I accomplish this with `bash` in further ?

Comment: Do you want to use `bash` for processing such text files? You could just use `grep` alone for this.

Comment: When I tried this: grep "github" urls.csv > github.com
I've got all github urls, so I think I am doing something wrong with for each loop

Comment: @Spopic: [you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -F -f domains.csv url.csv
```

Test Results:

```
$ cat wordlist 
github.com
youtube.com
facebook.com

$ cat urllist 
| URL                           |
| ------------------------------|
| http://github.com/name        |
| http://stackoverflow.com/name2|
| http://stackoverflow.com/name3|
| http://www.linkedin.com/name3 |

$ grep -F -f wordlist urllist 
| http://github.com/name        |
```

Comment: You should use `-F` flag too to treat the strings as literal and not regexp

Comment: `grep -Fxf domains.csv <(cut -d '[ |]' < url.csv)` would give you just the URLs, cutting out the whitespace and `|`.

Comment: @Inian considered your suggestion and added, but still without `-F` it gives desire o/p which OP wants